# Hardware wifi is diabled, but there is no disable button! How can I enable it?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

My Thinkpad 410s laptop has been working fine, running Ubuntu for quite some time.
Yesterday, my wifi stopped working out of the blue.

I've ran `rfkill list` and it shows the wifi adapter as blocked both on the software and hardware levels. I've ran `rfkill unblock all`, and this gets rid of the software level block.

However, my laptop doesn't seem to have any hardware level "block wifi" button. Does anyone know how I can re-enable my wifi? I checked the BIOS, and wifi is enabled there. I don't think anything physical happened to my wifi card, I believe the problem is software related, but I haven't find any software method to solve it.

**Update** - I forgot to mention this, but I have no obvious wifi button on my keyboard, even when counting FN keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That model has a wireless switch on the same side as the optical drive, under the express card  slot - look at the ['connectivity and ports' section of this random review](http://www.thinkpads.com/2010/03/01/review-lenovo-thinkpad-t410/).

The key combo for both thinkpads I have to do wireless things is fn f5, but iirc that's software based.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a wireless symbol in a different colour on one of the keys on your keyboard (probably one of the Function keys).  If you do find it, then hold the "Fn" key while pressing it once -- this may turn the Wireless NIC back on again.

(It's possible that it was toggled off by accident in this manner, or that some hardware-based power management shut it off automatically {although this is very rare and I've only encountered one laptop so far that had this feature in the hardware without needing software interaction}, etc.).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I've looked for this and there is no obvious wifi button, including FN keys. I tried some buttons with similar icons, but nothing did the trick.